# Parenthetical phrase or subordinating conjunction?

Tags: grammaticality, clauses

I've learned that starting a sentence with a subordinating conjunction such as "if" there must be a dependent and independent clause.  So to me the sentence,

> If not, we do not need to start its procedure.

is ungrammatical.  I'm getting tripped up by the fact "If not," could be a 
parenthetical phrase.

I was hoping someone would help me differentiate.

Note: The referenced example is found in an ETS dataset "of sentences with ordinal labels for grammaticality." https://github.com/EducationalTestingService/gug-data/blob/master/gug_annotations.tsv

Comment: Ask yourself: To what does "If not" refer? Compare your sentence to: "If it does [something], we do not need to start its procedure."

Comment: So it is a sentence fragment, right?

Comment: "If not," is certainly a fragment of something—probably an _if-clause!_ It implies an action or state with which its lack is contrasted, and which may appear in another independent clause.

Comment: Is it ungrammatical, though? Consider: "He must be ready. If not, we do not need to start the procedure." The second sentence refers to the first, but it's still a sentence in its own right. Here's another example containing a sentence that legitimately starts with *If not*: "If you want this to be an answer, tell me now. If not, remain silent." (Note that "If not" is not parenthetical - you can't throw it away without changing the meaning of the sentence.)

Comment: @Lawrence The sentence is not ungrammatical, but the OP has not provided context to provide a referent for the dependent clause. (By the way, the sentence without the putative parenthetical is entirely grammatical as well!)

Comment: @P. E. Dant  Unfortunately, I only have access to the sentence and not its context.  A sentence should be able to stand on its own, right?  In other words, are there situations where the grammaticality of a sentence is dependent on its context?

Comment: @Alw *Yes and no.* <--- Is that grammatical with no context?

Comment: _"A sentence should be able to stand on its own, right?"_ That is a foolish, foolish assumption. Context is everything.

Comment: Evaluate the grammaticality of the sentence: *Bananas.* Compare to that sentence's grammaticality in *Q: By what nickname does J.R.'s team of psychiatrists call him? A: Bananas.*

Answer (score 4):

> **If not**, we do not need to start its procedure.

This is grammatical, but *if not* isn't really a parenthetical phrase.  *If so* and *if not* are special reduced forms in which the pro-forms *so* and *not* stand for full finite clauses; *so* is positive and *not* is negative.

This is described on pages 757 and 1536 of *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, where we can find the following examples:

> 1. There'll probably be a vacancy in June; **if so**, we'll let you know.
> 2. We may be able to finish tomorrow; **if not** it will certainly be done by Friday.

In the former example, *if so* is interpreted as "if there is a vacancy in June", and in the latter example, *if not* is interpreted as "if we aren't able to finish tomorrow".

In your example, *so* refers back to a full finite clause from the preceding context.  Since you haven't supplied the context, I can't tell you what exactly it is, but you should understand it as standing for a clause.

Answer (score 0):

If not, I think, is kind of a set phrase. It is a shorthand for "if it is not". I suppose there is some type of verbless clause involved (it is a subordinate clause, if clause).